# Rabbitmq reporting different queue status than command-line tools

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I've run in to a problem wherein the RabbitMQ (RMQ) Web UI reports different numbers than the command-line tools. I may be misunderstanding the results, but I'll step though what I think is representative of the problem.

I'm using Celery as a task manager. When I submit a set of tasks, the queues fill up and the workers start churning out results. The RMQ UI, shows a list of ready, unacked, etc. messages (tasks). Meanwhile, if I look at the response from the command-line tools, I can get a list of the active, reserved, etc. messages (tasks on the worker). There seems to be a mismatch between these two sets of numbers, especially when the UI claims there are no messages left (tasks to be run), i.e. the queues have been drained.

While I know that UI numbers and the command-line results represent different views: i.e. one looks at the broker, while the other looks at the workers. It's my feeling that when the broker says there are no remaining messages, the workers should not be working on anything either. Unfortunately, this is not the case; instead I see that the workers are still busy consuming messages and executing tasks.

I though that if the workers ack'd on completion of the work, rather than when they receive the task, that there should be at least some messages reported in the Web UI's unacked column.

Comment: which rabbitmq version?

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.2.4, Pyhon 2.7.6.